# Flow velocity in exhaust chimney - typical design value

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm looking at a project where stationary CHP engines will be replaced, leaving as much of the infrastructure in place as possible. Current exhaust velocity in the chimney is ~42m/s and it will be a bit higher (~47m/s) with the new engines. I've seen 'around 40 m/s' as a typical exhaust velocity to design the chimney for, but I've also seen far smaller values and none of this with a source.

What is a 'good' design value for the exhaust velocity? Please provide a source/and or reasoning!

Comment: I'm not going to do the work so I'll leave this as a comment, but I would look at the air/fuel ratio in the engine and then perform the stoichiometric analysis to determine the exhaust gas formation rate per pound/kg/gallon/etc. of fuel. Take the exhaust gases, evaluate them at standard pressure but at the temperature at the end of your stack to find the specific volume of your exhaust. *Then*, knowing the volumetric exhaust gas production, you can try to estimate fuel consumption, convert that to a volume production,  then divide by $\pi r^2$, the effective chimney radius, for linear speed.

Comment: I say it like this because your question is very, very vague. What kind of engines do you have - 1/2 HP lawnmower engines or 500kW generators? How big is the chimney? How much load are the engines under? If you want a ballpark your own research is probably good enough; you also haven't stated what you're trying to use this for. If you are looking for a rigorous analysis, then you'll need to evaluate the scenario(s) you care about - fuel economy (load and efficiency), leanness of the burn, altitude/atmospheric pressure, etc. I don't know how accurately you're looking to estimate this.

Comment: I'm not looking for exhaust gas production (that's on the data sheet of the engine!), I'm looking wether the existing chimney is big enough. Out of curiosity, what question where you answering just now?

Comment: I don't understand your question then. You say, "What is a 'good' design value for the exhaust velocity?" Are you not trying to find exhaust velocity? Are you looking for *maximum* exhaust velocity *for a chimney* instead maybe? The question I was answering was the one I thought you had asked - how to find exhaust velocity (of an engine).

Comment: Also, earlier in your question you say, "I've seen ... a typical exhaust velocity to design the chimney **for**," where again it looks like you are asking how to find the exhaust gas velocity so you can find the right chimney. If exhaust velocity is the only criteria for evaluating sufficiency of size on the chimney, it would seem to me you already have everything you need as you indicated above. If it's not and you know exhaust velocity already, I'm not sure why you would mention exhaust velocity at all. Maybe you actually have another question - "How do I size an exhaust chimney?"?

Comment: I need to see If an existing chimney is sufficient for slightly bigger engines. I've given the flow velocities (as is and with bigger engines). The question: What are typical values for this?

Comment: The engines are 800kW CHP, max exhaust pressur is 60mbar.